# If there are vertices(eg: Star, Movie) and edges(eg: star_in, director, ...) in ArangoDB, how to query movies which starring and directed by someone?

Tags: arangodb

If there are vertices(eg: Star, Movie) and edges(eg: star_in, director, producer) in ArangoDB, and I want to get movies which starring and directed by Stephen Chow, how to write the query statement?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the AQL NEIGHBORS function:

```
FOR n IN ANY @startId @@edgeCollection OPTIONS {bfs:true,uniqueVertices: 'global'}
RETURN n._id
```

`ANY/INBOUND/OUTBOUND` determines the direction of the edges while @startId is your start vertex (in this case Stephen Crow) and @@edgecollection is your used edge collection.

When two conditions should be applied (starring and directed) a INTERSECTION of two NEIGHBOUR queries could be used.

The following AQL query is a draft for your use case:

```
FOR x IN INTERSECTION
  ((FOR y IN ANY 'star/StephenChow' star_in OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global'} RETURN y._id),
  (FOR y IN ANY 'star/StephenChow' director OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global'} RETURN y._id))
  RETURN x
```

A working Actor/Movie example can be found in the [Cookbook](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Cookbook/Graph/ExampleActorsAndMovies.html) section of the documentation.

Comment: You mean query them(starring and directed) seperately and calculate their intersection? Beyond that, is there a more direct way to get the results?

Comment: Yes, the first "FOR y..." returns all movies where "StephenChow" is starring in and the second one returns "FOR y..." the movies that he directed. "FOR x..." calculates the intersection of these separately calculated neighbors. This would be my approach to get the requested result.